# How to find recurrence of an unsorted array A of n integers with no duplicates and prove it

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to understand this sorting algorithm below. This is to be done in C

```
sort(A, i, j):
  if i = j then
    return
  end if
  m = floor(i+j/2)
  sort(A, i, m)
  sort(A, m + 1, j)
  if A[m] > A[j] then
    swap A[m] and A[j]
  end if
  sort(A, i, j − 1)
```

First, I am trying to write a recurrence that characterizes the runtime of `sort(A, 0, n − 1)`. And also, how should I prove the algorithm is correct using induction? Need help, please.

Comment: Can you give a bit of context around this (like, what programming language are you using, and what problem are you trying to solve?) Otherwise, I'm going to assume that you have literally posted a homework question here and asked stackoverflow to do your homework for you, from soup to nuts.

I'd be happy to give you a hint, but I won't do your homework for you, and no one else should either.

Comment: Very interesting question. The recurrence comes in two parts - d'n'c part and linear part. I would like to see how it can be solved. For now i see that it is not polynomial, but O(2^n) is not a tight bound.